# How to trigger a custom javascript event in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, requirejs

I'm trying to fire a custom event on IE8 and fiddling a solution together from [here](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2009/03/callbacks-vs-events/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342917/custom-events-in-ie-without-using-libraries). But I cannot get it to work...

I'm using jquery mobile with requireJS and google analytics. So I'm tracking the JQM `pageshow` event. However since requireJS loads scripts async, my binding to pageshow needs to be made in a javascript "wrapper", otherwise it will produce an error, because neither jquery nor jquery mobile will have been loaded by the time the snippet is parsed.

So I'm doing including this at the end of every page:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("jqmReady",function(){trigAnalytics("jqmReady");alert("FF detected")},false); 
} else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
    document.attachEvent("jqmReady", function(){trigAnalytics("jqmReady");alert("IE detected")}); 
}
```

And when detected, I'm firing my analytics snippet with the pageshow binding:

```
var trigAnalytics = function( trigger ){ 
    $(document).on('pageshow','div:jqmData(role="page").basePage', function (event, ui) {
        var url = location.href; 
        try { 
            hash = location.hash; 
            if (hash && hash.length > 1) {
                 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', hash.substr(1)]);
                 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'id_external', ########, 1 ]);
            } else {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);
                _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'id_external', ########, , 1 ]);
                _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview', url]);
            } 
        } catch(err) { } 
    }); 
    if (typeof _gaq !== "undefined" && _gaq !== null) { 
        $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){ 
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', settings.url]); 
            _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview', settings.url]);
        }); 
    } 
};
```

So to kick of the event chain, I need to trigger `jqmReady` when JQM is ready. JQM uses their `mobileinit` event to indicate just that. So inside my application controller init, I'm binding to it like so:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

    // non-IE OK
    if (document.createEvent) {
        evt = document.createEvent("Event");
        evt.initEvent("jqmReady", true, true);
        document.dispatchEvent(evt);

    } else if (document.createEventObject) { 
    // MSIE (NOT WORKING)

        document.documentElement.evt = 0; // an expando property
        document.documentElement.attachEvent("jqmReady", function () {
            document.documentElement.evt = document.documentElement.evt + 1;
            });
    }
});
```

I have tried just triggering $(window).trigger('jqmReady'), because when `mobileinit` triggers, jquery is available. However it seems events created in `addEventListener` can not be triggered like this, so I need a javascript-only solution to trigger a custom event in IE.

**Question:**
Can someone give me a pointer on how to trigger a javascript custom event for IE8 correctly?

Comment: why not place that trigger in $(document).ready() ? why you can need that at all ?

Comment: Because `jquery` ~ $(document).ready() will not be available when this code runs. The snippet is on the page right after the requireJS initialization. So the (1) page is parsed, (2) requireJS triggers, (3) my snippet executes. When it does, neither `jquery` or `jquery-mobile` will have fully loaded. So, must be javascript-only.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question (hence comment, not answer) but is [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) of relevance?

Comment: Which part is not clear? Bottom line is I need to find a way to trigger a custom event in javascript only, which works on IE8. Let me check `dispatchEvent`.

Comment: @frequent, ah lol jquery mobile.... http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html
**Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()**

Comment: @eicto: :-) (and 4 characters)

Comment: @DavidThomas: From what I understand `dispatchEvent` cannot be used for custom events, such as my `jqmReady` event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I finally understand... here is how it works:

1) setting the listener for jqmReady on the page being loaded

```
// non-IE: just create a listener for the custom event "jqmReady"
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("jqmReady",function(){trigAnalytics("jqmReady");alert("FF detected")},false); 
// IE8
} else if ( document.attachEvent ) {

    // create a custom property name jqmReady and set it to 0
    document.documentElement.jqmReady = 0;
    // since IE8 does not allow to listen to custom events, 
    // just listen to onpropertychange
    document.documentElement.attachEvent("onpropertychange", function(event) {

        // if the property changed is the custom jqmReady property
        if (event.propertyName == "jqmReady") {
            trigAnalytics("jqmReady");
            alert("gotcha")
            // remove listener, since it's only used once
            document.documentElement.detachEvent("onpropertychange", arguments.callee);
        }
    });
}
```

So on IE8 I'm not listening for custom `jqmReady`. Instead I listen for `onpropertychange` for my custom property `jqmReady`

2) Then on mobileinit I'm triggering like this:

```
 // non-IE
 if (document.createEvent) {
      evt = document.createEvent("Event");
      evt.initEvent("jqmReady", true, true);
      document.dispatchEvent(evt);
 } else if (document.createEventObject) { // MSIE
      // just change the property 
      // this will trigger onpropertychange
      document.documentElement.jqmReady++;
 };
```

Nice idea (credit to http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2009/03/callbacks-vs-events/), maybe someone else can find a use for it.

Comment: One downside to `onpropertychange` is that it doesn't bubble though. You have to know in advance which element has its property changed. More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else interested, I've wrapped up this code into a static javascript object

```
function Event () {
}

Event.listen = function (eventName, callback) {
    if(document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else {    
        document.documentElement.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function (e) {
            if(e.propertyName  == eventName) {
                callback();
            }            
        });
    }
}

Event.trigger = function (eventName) {
    if(document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        document.documentElement[eventName]++;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Event.listen('myevent', function () {
    alert('myevent triggered!');
});

Event.trigger('myevent');
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/c5CuF/

Comment: nice. You could add a `.remove` method to properly dispose of the custom event.

Comment: You should clarify what you do in line 34 in your gist, to get rid of the eval statement. `document.documentElement[eventName]++`