# In IE8: Create a custom event in vanilla JS and pick it up in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

All of this is happening for IE8.

Due to script import orders, I'm having a bit of code being executed **before** JQuery is loaded where I need to fire a custom event.

This event will be picked up later in another bit of code when I'm sure JQuery will have been loaded. So I'd like to use JQuery to pick up this event.

I saw this previously asked question: [How to trigger a custom javascript event in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435008/how-to-trigger-a-custom-javascript-event-in-ie8) and applied the answer, which worked, but when I'm trying to pick up the Event via JQuery, then nothing happens.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
function Event() {}

Event.listen = function(eventName, callback) {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
  } else {
    document.documentElement.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function(e) {
      if (e.propertyName == eventName) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
};

Event.trigger = function(eventName) {
  if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    document.documentElement[eventName] ++;
  }
};



Event.listen('myevent', function() {
  document.getElementById('mydiv-jquery').innerText = "myevent jquery";
});

$(document).on('myevent', function() {
  document.getElementById('mydiv-vanilla').innerText = "myevent vanilla";
});

Event.trigger('myevent');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv-jquery">Nothing</div>
<div id="mydiv-vanilla">Nothing</div>
```

**PS:** The snippet doesn't seem to work properly in IE. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toce6enq/1/) that should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code.

- You shadow the built-in `window.Event` without checking if it exists; this could cause problems for other scripts.
- You don't preserve the `this` binding when calling the callback from your `onpropertychange` listener. You should apply the callback to the document rather than calling it directly so the behavior will be as close as possible to `addEventListener`.
- You attempt to increment `document.documentElement[eventName]` while it is undefined. The first call will change the value to `NaN`, so `onpropertychange` should pick it up, but on subsequent calls it will remain `NaN`.
- You make no attempt to have `.on()` recognize your `Event.listen` function, so naturally the code in `Event.listen` will never be executed from a listener attached with `.on()`.

Have you tried using Andrea Giammarchi's [CustomEvent](https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/6693661) shim?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problems you noticed are duly noted :) I'll be sure to correct those as soon as I can my hands on the code again. I did not know about this shim, so I'll check it out as well. As for your last point, would you have any lead on how to do such a thing ?