# Retrigger onclick in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I want to change and trigger `onclick` function during `onclick` event.

Event triggering is used from [Custom events in IE without using libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342917/custom-events-in-ie-without-using-libraries)

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function triggerEvent(el,eventName){
    var event;
    if(document.createEvent){
        event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        event.initEvent(eventName,true,true);
    }else if(document.createEventObject){// IE < 9
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = eventName;
    }
    event.eventName = eventName;
    if(el.dispatchEvent){
        el.dispatchEvent(event);
    }else if(el.fireEvent && htmlEvents['on'+eventName]){// IE < 9
        el.fireEvent('on'+event.eventType,event);// can trigger only real event (e.g. 'click')
    }else if(el[eventName]){
        el[eventName]();
    }else if(el['on'+eventName]){
        el['on'+eventName]();
    }
}

function firstClick(obj) {
  console.log("1st click");
  obj.onclick = function() {
    console.log("2nd click");
  }
  triggerEvent(obj, "click");
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;" onclick="firstClick(this);"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output on the first click is `1st click 2nd click` in most browsers (IE7, Chrome, Firefox) but IE11. In IE11 output is just `1st click`.

What can be done with this?

Comment: Can't you go with jQuery `obj.trigger("click");` ?

Comment: @Jaay, If I'm not mistaken, it was correct answer. Thanks.