# what is equivalent of document.createEventObject() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to replace  document.createEventObject() with a jquery to or in IE 11

```
 var ev = document.createEventObject();
    ev.item = currSelectedItem;
    document.event = ev;
```

Could you please suggest.

Comment: jQuery uses a different event layer above the native events, so I don't think you can replace it with jQuery.

Comment: createEventObject is not defined in IE 11. Is there any other option in javascript ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ ?

Comment: @Grasshopper See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11181451/283863)